# Regular expression to filter special characters not working

Tags: regex, regular-language

i am searching for a regular expression i can use to check if a user input contains special characters in a specified list.

Here are the special characters not allowed by using a regular expression i tried to write: `` ^[`~!@#$%^&*()_+={}\[\]|\\:;“’<,>.?๐฿]*$ ``

i went to https://regex101.com/ and i was expecting the following input to match but did it not why:

```
127 elmer road ??<>()
```

so in android java (but an be any ) i wrote the following function but it also always returns true . how can i filter all these special characters . I want a function that returns true if a given string does NOT match.

```
  public boolean isValid( EditText et) {
            String string = et.getText().toString();
            boolean isValid = true;

             final Pattern sPattern
                    = Pattern.compile("^[`~!@#$%^&*()_+={}\\[\\]|\\\\:;“’<,>.?๐฿]*$");

            isValid=  !sPattern.matcher(string).matches();


            return isValid;
        }
```

update:  i tried the following also:

[image]

Comment: Your regex expects a start of string, a single character in the list, and then the end.  Try something like this:  `^.*[~!@#$%^&()_+={}[\]|\:;“’<,>.?๐฿].*$`  Note, you need to escape the `]`.

Comment: when i tried that i got an exception . but also the IDe gave a complaint of"  Pattern.compile("^.*[~!@#$%^&()_+={}[]|\\:;“’<,>.?๐฿].*$"); unclosed character class". this was at the very end after the $.   it let me run the program but i got the following exception:    java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion: ^

Comment: Note my edit - escape the `]`

Comment: Why do you have `^` and `$` in your regex?

Comment: can you tell me what i should do then ? i mean i was trying to do the "NOT" of that. really i just need . a regular espression that removes all these special chars.  and im using the *$ to say that zero or more characters can follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want a function that returns true if a given string does NOT match.

You can negate the character set. (Note the `^` symbol within the square brackets). This will return true for strings that don't contain any of these special characters.

```
^[^`~!@#$%^&*()_+={}\[\]|\\:;“’<,>.?๐฿]*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/CqtqoK/1